# I just installed with logon automatically, updated Ubuntu, now it asks for password when I reboot

Tags: login, password

Can't login in from 
Ubuntu 19.10, generic desktop system
It won't take the password asked for during install.
It will login without password if I choose advanced options in grub, then generic recovery mode .40.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since it is a new installation, I'll re-install so I have to login, and then try the automatic login later.

Comment: Is the problem with login? Or is the problem with "unlock keyring" ?